# Bootstrap wordpress theme displaying strange white div in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Good day! I have a problem regarding with my converted wordpress theme. I just converted this from static HTML to wordpress using bootstrap framework. Now my problem is after the conversion when I open it using chrome a strange problem is happening such as the screenshot below.

**Homepage:**

[image]

**Other pages and Search result page:**

[image]

but with firefox everything is fine.

Comment: As you didn't post any links, I can only suppose, but if there is a div up there, try to set a background: transparent to explicitly set the background to invisible.

Comment: Or you could post a link to your work in progress.

Comment: Its on my localhost. This is so strange for me though.

Comment: This might be a problem with the top header bar, but you need to provide the code of the home.php / index.php and header.php for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: a code of my header:
http://pastebin.com/MQbm9eTq

Comment: if this is the whole code, first of all, you have one closing div to much.

And a bit of CSS code would help to understand what's going on. What does "pagefixer" do? or "headbg"? and why do you use "column" and the "col-md-" from bootstrap? maybe those do something weird. But post CSS, and we'll take a look.

Comment: yes col-md is from bootstrap.here is the link of other css.and im still playing with pagefixer

http://pastebin.com/EktgN2M7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution. It is because i was not able to add the wordpress function about the admin toolbar.